# Instagram API - Can they provide likes amount?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Need to work with the Instagram API
Need these types of data, when I search an Instagram Hashtag `#`

- Get All recent posts with this hashtag
- Get Comments_Count, Likes_Count
- Account name (of post writer)
- Image URL (of post)
- URL of post

I tried to work with the `Instagram Graph API`, having a bit difficulty since its API looks quite different than other APIs, did you manage to find where they put it?

Comment: How many hashtags are you going to be trying to get?  IG API has a pretty low limit on hashtag requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the relevant reference for hashtags, but you can see that there are some significant restrictions on the endpoint.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/

You can get data for 30 hashtags a week per Business or Creator account that has authorized your app, so the endpoint is not that useful outside of a few use cases.

If you don't need to track that many hashtags, I believe you can get all of the information EXCEPT the Account Name for the post creator.  You would need to register and code an app that can pass review for the Instagram Public Content Access feature and the instagram_basic permission, and then the Business or Creator account would need to authorize your app (and keep it authorized).